# referencing the same table twice in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can someone please tell me if there is an isuse with entity framework if you try to reference the same table twice?

For example, I have 3 tables

- Story
- Users
- Xref_users.

  The story Has a user Id to identify the owner but also needs to have a collection of users who can view it.

  When I create the edmx it makes the proper navigation to user but not to Users. Instead it refrences xref_user.

Now I did the same thing with 3 other tables

- Votes
- Entry
- Xref_Votes

The edmx recoginized this right away and created the navigation votes under Entry.

The only difference I can see here is that Story references User twice

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the Story entity?  Does story have an 'author' and 'readers' instead of just 'users'?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. It looks like `Xref_users` is a join table. A join table should contain only the primary keys of the 2 tables involved in the many-to-many relationship. Hence the `Xref_users` columns should look like

- UserId  (PK, FK to Users)
- StoryId (PK, FK to Story)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Xref_users has another column and since EF supports only [many to many without "payload"](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/db6df279-a925-443c-a616-7375867409a6/), the tool created the navigation property between story and xref_users and not, as expected, between story and users